# Conditional probability VS A Intersection B

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, monty-hall

I recently came across the Monty Hall Problem. And while I get the gist of it, what I am having trouble understanding is this specific part of it.

Say I pick door 1. 
Then the probabilities for the following are as follows:
$$P(P_1:S_2)=\frac16$$
$$P(P_1:S_3)=\frac16$$
$$P(P_2:S_3)=\frac13$$
$$P(P_3:S_2)=\frac13$$
Where $P_3:S_2$ is the probability that the prize is behind door number 3, AND Monty opens door 2. I don’t understand these numbers. If he opens door 3, and the prize is behind door 2, hasn’t our probability increased from being a third to a half?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to go by the hard probabilities. After door $3$ is shown, the probabilities $P(P_i:S_3)$ drop to zero, and the other probabilities $P(P_i:S_2)$ *increase proportionally so as to sum to one*. They do not equalise as you (and indeed many others who are shown the problem for the first time) think. So $P(P_3:S_2)$ is now $\frac23$.

I like to think about it this way: $\frac23$ of the time, your door contains a goat, and Monty's hand is *forced*. He has to open the door with the other goat, and switching wins you the prize. The other $\frac13$ of the time your door contains the prize, and switching will win you only a goat.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your first sentence. "After door 3 is shown, the probabilities (:2) drop to zero, and the other probabilities (:3) increase proportionally so as to sum to one". What is Pi? also, I am showing door 2, right? Not door 3?

Comment: @Oishika $P_i$ simply means $P_1$, $P_2$ and $P_3$ comvined.